# Change SQL Server Analysis Services permissions set during install

Tags: sql-server, permissions, installation, ssas

While installing SQL Server 2008 (which included SSAS), I set these permissions, giving a domain group that held our SQL Service Account:
[image: SQL Server Installation Step - Cluster Security Policy]
<sub>(source: [trycatchfinally.net](http://trycatchfinally.net/uploadedimages/ssas%20permissions.gif))</sub>  .

Now I need to change that group to a different one that includes a second service account, but I'm not able to conclusively find the permissions it set. There was overlap with our last domain group, so it's almost impossible to separate permissions, but I'm hoping somebody can help me step in the right direction.

Though all would be interesting, I'm especially interested in the AS entry - the last one in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was posted almost a month ago but I believe once you set those domain groups the only way to change them is to uninstall/reinstall SQL Server. Of course, you can alaways change service accounts but the domains will remain the same unfortunately =(. It's also recommended that if you're running 2008, as you stated, to use service SIDs for SQL Server services.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: 25 points to you for submitting an answer - this is exactly what I discovered a few days after I posted this question. I'm surprised that there's no way to change these groups - you'd think that they're stored somewhere, and there would be some way to change them, but a full un-/re-install seemed to be my only choice.

Comment: Thanks, I know how hard it is to find answers about SSAS out there since it's pretty high level stuff.